# insert data from one table into another

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables

```
T1
Id  |     City
1   |Van Nuys
2   |Diamond Bar
3   |Anaheim

T2
Id  |     City
1   |Burbank
2   |N.Hollywood
3   |Van Nuys
```

And I need to populate T1 with data from T2 . To get

```
T1
Id  |     City
1   |Van Nuys
2   |Diamond Bar
3   |Anaheim  
4   |Burbank
5   |N.Hollywood
```

I tried something like

```
const char *insert_sql = "INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t2";
```

I think it is not inserting data from t2 into t1 because they have same id.

What is the statement to perform this operation?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if your tables are in the same database:

```
INSERT INTO t1(City)
    SELECT City from t2 WHERE City NOT IN (SELECT City From t1)
```

If your tables are NOT in the same database, you'll have to:

- open a connection to database1.
- query for the records you want - `SELECT City FROM t1;`. Save this into a local collection in memory.
- close the connection to database1
- open a connection to database2
- loop through your collection; for each record, load into a string variable like `#SomeCity`
- run a SQL `INSERT` statement like so: `INSERT INTO t2(City) VALUES (#SomeCity);`
- close the connection to database2

Comment: Thanks for response. I forgot to add that my t1 and t2 tables are in different databases(db1 and db2 respectively). what should I do in this case? Do I need ATTACH DATADASE ?